# how to remove some numerical text from a cell (not total entry of the cell) if it has a special carecter? excel

Tags: excel, trim

I have this excel sheet which has some questions. they are in cell no. a1, a2, a3 ....... and so on.

Each question has a number assigned to it like the following.

1. what is your hair color?
2. where is tower hamlet?
3. how to cock 5 potato?
4. Is number 10 greater then number 2?

etc.

You see each question number has a (.) assigned next to it.

I want to remove any numerical value which has (.) next to it.
so that I have only the text question and not the numbers.

Comment: simple string find first . take right for lenth of cell minus location of  first .

Answer (score 1):

For your example Replace `*.` should work.

Answer (score 0):

This will take the right most values less the "#. space"

`=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(".",A1)-1)`

[image]